# Multi-Part Identifier - Namespace Issue I believe

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
USE VISION_DB

SELECT
tpi.ProfileName,
tic.ChannelName

FROM
T_PROFILE_INFO tpi,
T_INPUT_CHANNEL_INFO tic,
T_PROFILE_CHANNELS

INNER JOIN
T_PROFILE_CHANNELS tpc ON tpc.ProfileID = ***T_PROFILE_INFO.ProfileID***
    AND tpc.ChannelID = ***T_INPUT_CHANNEL_INFO.ChannelID***
```

I am able to return the multi-part identifier alert for each of the two entries highlighted.

The alias `tpc` is referenced correctly, but the right side of each expression will not. I have substituted the alias' from the `FROM` clause, but they are out of scope here.

I have been trying to sort this for some time. I believe there is a namespace issue, but do not know how to reference the changes required.

I run across this issue regularly, but have always been able to resolve it with a search. I can find nothing that appears to clear this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE VISION_DB

SELECT tpi.ProfileName, tic.ChannelName

FROM T_PROFILE_INFO tpi

   INNER JOIN T_PROFILE_CHANNELS tpc 
        ON tpc.ProfileID = tpi.ProfileID
   INNER JOIN T_INPUT_CHANNEL_INFO tic
        ON tpc.ChannelID = tic.ChannelID
```

You seem to be mixing two styles of syntax:  the older style, which looks like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   table1, table2, table3
 WHERE  table1.col1 = table2.col1 
   AND  table2.col2 = table3.col2
```

... with the newer, more powerful syntax:

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM    table1
    INNER JOIN  table2
        ON  table1.col1 = table2.col1 
    INNER JOIN  table3
        ON  table2.col2 = table3.col2
```

I can't say for sure (because I never tried) that you can't mix them, but I don't advise it.  I'd suggest picking one style (my preference would be for the newer, more powerful syntax) and sticking with it.

Also:  once you give a table an alias, you can't reference it by its actual name.  Once you alias `T_PROFILE_INFO` as `tpi`, you can't reference its columns as `T_PROFILE_INFO.Column1` anymore:  you have to refer to them as `tpi.Column1`.

Comment: Tried those earlier...they appear to be out of scope within the join, I believe

Comment: Try dropping `T_PROFILE_CHANNELS` out of your `FROM` clause, and using the aliases in your `JOIN` statements.  That might help.

Comment: @KenBartlett  I think so.  Once you give a table an alias, you have to refer to its columns using the alias:  you can't refer to them by the table name anymore.  (See the last paragraph of my answer for an example.)

Comment: I was not aware that I could separate the statement in the join. I had always used AND to link multiple tables, where seveal evaluations were needed to qualify the response....table1.column1 = table 2.column1 AND table1.column1 = table 3.column1. vs what you've done....Cheers.

Comment: @KenBartlett  Did my answer help you?  If so, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Thank you!